# Show label probability/confidence in NLTK

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I'm using the MaxEnt classifier from the Python NLTK library. For my dataset, I have many possible labels, and as expected, MaxEnt returns just one label. I have trained my dataset and get about 80% accuracy. I've also tested my model on unknown data items, and the results are good. However, for any given unknown input, I want to be able to print/display a ranking of all the possible labels based on some internal criteria MaxEnt used to select the one, such as confidence/probability. For example, suppose I had `a,b,c` as possible labels and I use `MaxEnt.classify(input)`, I get currently one label, let's say `c`. However, I want to be able to view something like `a (0.9), b(0.7), c(0.92)`, so I can see why `c` was selected, and possibly choose multiple labels based on those parameters. Apologies for my fuzzy terminology, I'm fairly new to NLP and machine learning.

**Solution**

Based on the accepted answer, here's a skeleton code example to demonstrate what I wanted and how it can be achieved. More classifier examples on the [NLTK website](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html).

```
import nltk

contents = read_data('mydataset.csv')
data_set = [(feature_sets(input), label) for (label, input) in contents] # User-defined feature_sets() function
train_set, test_set = data_set[:1000], data_set[1000:]
labels = [label for (input, label) in train_set]
maxent = nltk.MaxentClassifier.train(train_set)
maxent.classify(feature_sets(new_input)) # Returns one label
multi_label = maxent.prob_classify(feature_sets(new_input)) # Returns a DictionaryProbDist object
for label in labels:
    multi_label.prob(label)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `prob_classify(input)`

It returns dictionary with probability for each label, see [docs](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/maxent.html).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm looking for! However, how do I iterate through the returned `DictionaryProbDist` object? I've found the class documentation and have tested the `max()` method, but I'd like to print out each label and  associated probability: http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/probability.html

Comment: Never mind, got it. I've added a more complete code example to show what I wanted and how it can be achieved