# It is possible to show label probability in scikit-learn for several models?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nltk

I have a VoteClassifier model that consist in the followings algorithms:

- Bayesian classifier
- SVC
- LinearSVC
- NuSVC
- MNB
- BernoulliNB
- LogisticRegression

I have trained some data to get probability and probability for all the possible labels, for example, if I have two labels: x and y, and probability method of a featureset results in x, then I want to know that was the result probability for x and y labels. According with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29398403/6796652) I'm using `prob_classify` (documentation [here](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/maxent.html)) function from `ClassifierI` method of `nltk.clssify` module to achieve that thing, and the idea is that at the end of this calculation, get the average of all the probabilities to show a final probability for the two labels, but it doesn't work for all the models, specifically for Support Vector Machine models.
I explain below the scenario with a similary reproducible code:

```
from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC, LinearSVC, NuSVC
from nltk import classify, NaiveBayesClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB,BernoulliNB
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression,SGDClassifier
import random

dataset = [
    (dict(a=1,b=1,c=1), 'y'),
    (dict(a=1,b=1,c=1), 'x'),
    (dict(a=1,b=1,c=0), 'y'),
    (dict(a=0,b=1,c=1), 'x'),
    (dict(a=0,b=1,c=1), 'y'),
    (dict(a=0,b=0,c=1), 'y'),
    (dict(a=0,b=1,c=0), 'x'),
    (dict(a=0,b=0,c=0), 'x'),
    (dict(a=0,b=1,c=1), 'y'),
]

random.shuffle(dataset)
slice_size = round(len(dataset)*70/100)
train_data, test_data = dataset[:slice_size], dataset[slice_size:]

#------ This works fine --------------

Bayesian_classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_data)
dist = Bayesian_classifier.prob_classify((dict(a=0,b=1,c=1)))
print ("x:"+str(dist.prob('x')),"y:"+str(dist.prob('y')))

MultinomialNB_classifier = SklearnClassifier(MultinomialNB())
MultinomialNB_classifier.train(train_data)
dist = MultinomialNB_classifier.prob_classify((dict(a=0,b=1,c=1)))
print ("x:"+str(dist.prob('x')),"y:"+str(dist.prob('y')))

BernoulliNB_classifier = SklearnClassifier(BernoulliNB())
BernoulliNB_classifier.train(train_data)
dist = BernoulliNB_classifier.prob_classify((dict(a=0,b=1,c=1)))
print ("x:"+str(dist.prob('x')),"y:"+str(dist.prob('y')))

LogisticRegression_classifier = SklearnClassifier(LogisticRegression())
LogisticRegression_classifier.train(train_data)
dist = LogisticRegression_classifier.prob_classify((dict(a=0,b=1,c=1)))
print ("x:"+str(dist.prob('x')),"y:"+str(dist.prob('y')))

#------ But this doesn't work --------------

SVC_classifier = SklearnClassifier(SVC())
SVC_classifier.train(train_data)
SVC_classifier.prob_classify((dict(a=0,b=1,c=1)))

LinearSVC_classifier = SklearnClassifier(LinearSVC())
LinearSVC_classifier.train(train_data)
LinearSVC_classifier.prob_classify((dict(a=0,b=1,c=1)))

NuSVC_classifier = SklearnClassifier(NuSVC())
NuSVC_classifier.train(train_data)
NuSVC_classifier.prob_classify((dict(a=0,b=1,c=1)))
```

I got the following error with the last three SVC models:

```
    raise AttributeError("predict_proba is not available when "
AttributeError: predict_proba is not available when  probability=False
```

Also I tried with SGDClassifier but i got a different error:

```
SGDClassifier_classifier = SklearnClassifier(SGDClassifier())
SGDClassifier_classifier.train(train_data)
SGDClassifier_classifier.prob_classify((dict(a=0,b=1,c=1)))
```

```
 line 984, in _check_proba
    " loss=%r" % self.loss)
AttributeError: probability estimates are not available for loss='hinge'
```

**So my question is:**
I think that not all the sklearn models supports `prob_classify()` function, but if I do for example:

```
>>> dir(SVC_classifier)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__unicode__', '__weakref__', '_clf', '_encoder', '_make_probdist', '_vectorizer', 'classify', 'classify_many', 'labels', 'prob_classify', 'prob_classify_many', 'train', 'unicode_repr']
```

I got `prob_classify()` function as a possible option, the same thing with `SGDClassifier_classifier`, so what I'm missing? it's possible or not? and please explain me why.

At the moment, I can get the final result but only with Bayesian, MNB, BernoulliNB and LogisticRegression algorithms. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Those models implement `predic_proba` function but it is not available for all the possible configurations of those models.

For example, SVMs by default do not predict probabilities if you look into their mathematical definition. They just the find best separating hyperplane and tell you on which side the point is (positive/negative).

To allow SVMs in sklearn to output probabilities, you need to change the setting `probability` to `True` when you are instantiating the SVC class (internally, this will run the SVC's output through the logistic regression to get the probability).

```
clf = SVC(probability=True)
```

The same goes `SGDClassifier` which doesn't support `predict_proba` when you are using the default hinge loss.

Comment: It worked fine with ```SVC``` and ```NuSVC``` and I get the same result, so I suposs that I got that result because as you say, both of them uses the same process with logistic regression, so I consider to use only one of them (the best of them according with the ```classify()``` function) for my ```VoteClassifier``` model. So thanks for your explanation.